# Unable to execute nodejs simple-ssh module's .exec() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using npm's simple-ssh module to connect to remote host as a root user.
I have one more superuser account `serviceUser`. I need to do an `su` to this user and execute a couple of commands. But the `su serviceUser`(Note:`su serviceUser` is passwordless) is not getting executed.
Code is below:

```
var ssh = new SSH({
            host: hostserver,
            user: 'root',
            timeout: 1500000,
            key: require('fs').readFileSync("D:/Keys_pair_prvt_pub/rsa_key"),
            agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
            agentForward: true
            });
ssh
    .exec('whoami',{
        out: function(stdout) {
            logs += stdout;
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    })
    .exec('su serviceUser',{
        out: function(stdout) {
            logs += stdout;
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    })
    .exec('sh myScript.sh',{
        out: function(stdout) {
            logs += stdout;
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    })
    .exec('echo "exiting shell"',{
        out: function(){
            try{
                ssh.end();
                console.log("exiting");
                defer.resolve(obj);
            } catch(err){
                defer.reject(err);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

The `.exec('whoami',{` block is getting executed, but `.exec('su serviceUser',{` block doesn't.
In the output console I am getting `root` as output because of `whoami` but after that nothing happens.
Please help.

Comment: When you run 'su', it executes a shell (like `/bin/bash`) as a specific user. So the reason that the command blocks is probably because it has started bash and is now waiting for commands over stdin. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @brm, I am trying to run a few commands as `serviceUser` account..lets say `sh myScript.sh` needs to be run as `serviceUser`. For this I need to use `su serviceUser` but then its not working.

Comment: Do you need to just start the second script or does the first program need to send commands to it as well?

Comment: @brm, I need to start the main program as `root` user. Then I need to execute the command `sh myScript.sh` as `serviceUser`. So basically I need to do something like: `su serviceUser "sh myScript.sh"`.

Comment: Instead of using `su`, you could also drop your root privileges with `process.setuid` and `process.setgid`

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar but different issue. It's hard to say what your case was four years ago, but in case anyone comes here again, here is the code that I used to catch my similar but different error where simply "nothing happened". (I'm not sure why this is one of the last things they mention because it's something nearly everyone will want to use.)

From [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh), assuming an error is thrown in the connection or ssh process itself, this should catch it and spit out a stack trace.:

```js
ssh.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Oops, something went wrong.');
    console.log(err);
    ssh.end();
});
```

Furthermore, in addition to stdout handler `out:`'s, to get errors for each exec command, it would be a good idea to add some `err:`'s in the handlers, like so:

```js
{
    out: function (stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
    },
    err: function (stderr) {
        console.error('! ERROR !', stderr);
    },
}
```